# Can not give input to a java program using PHP shell_exec()

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

I want to run a java code, give input and store output using PHP Shell_Exec()..How can I do it?

**N:B:** I can run a java code and get output like this:

```
putenv('C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin');
    shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\codeland');
    shell_exec('javac Src.java');
    $userOutput=shell_exec('java Src');
```

But I can not give input in this program,,I want to give some input and then store the output.

Answer (score 0):

I get it!! My problem has been solved!! Here is my code:

```
putenv('C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin');
    shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\codeland');
    shell_exec('javac Src.java');
    $userOutput=shell_exec('java Src < testInput.txt');
    echo $userOutput;
```